# Is there any other method to draw the cross section but without using FF'E'E plane?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given that a regular pyramid `T.ABCD` in which

- `P` is on `TC` such that `TP:PC = 1:3`
- `R` is on the extension of `BC` such that `BR:BC = 1:3`
- `Q` is arbitrarily on the plane `TAD` but neither outside nor on the boundary

Draw the cross section when the plane `PQR` cuts the pyramid.

My own solution is as follows.

[image]

## Question

Is there any other method to draw the cross section but without using `FF'E'E` plane?

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

We have that given $P, Q$ and $R$ follows $\vec n = (Q-P)\times(R-P)$and the sought plane is given by

$$
\Pi \to (p-Q)\cdot\vec n = 0
$$

with $p = (x,y,z)$

Comment: Is it possible without geometry analytic approach? It is a high school math problem without calculus and geometry analytic.